# Can the Facebook API give location of user on mobile device?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, geolocation

I've found that it's easy to obtain 'current location' of Facebook users based on what they manually enter in on their profile. However, I'm curious if a Facebook user logs into my app with their FB log-in, can I get their location data as they go from one place to the next? For example, my app recommends the user go to a certain location. I want to know if that user actually goes to that location. I don't need to know their location down to the minute, just periodically where they end up, maybe every half hour or hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible via the Graph API or SDK. You could track the GPS location via the device's sensor data if you're creating an own app for iOS or Android for example.